# Странные полоски в паттерне

Tags: svg

Пробую сделать такой `pattern`, и непонятно откуда появляются вертикальные полоски, которых быть не должно.

При этом сам элемент `pattern`'a если вывести (смотрите пример) никаких полосок нет.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.c1 {
  fill: #ffd77a;
  stroke: #ffd77a;
}

.c2 {
  fill: #ffed7a;
  stroke: #ffed7a;
}

.c3 {
  fill: #fbff7a;
  stroke: #fbff7a;
}

.c4 {
  fill: #e4ff7a;
  stroke: #e4ff7a;
}

.c5 {
  fill: #ceff7a;
  stroke: #ceff7a;
}

.c6 {
  fill: #b8ff7a;
  stroke: #b8ff7a;
}

.c7 {
  fill: #a2ff7a;
  stroke: #a2ff7a;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" style="width:400px; height: 400px;" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="el1" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"></rect>
            <path d="M 30 0 L 0 30 L 0 0 Z" class="c5"></path>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="big1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform=""/>
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform="scale(-1, -1)"/>
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform="scale(-1, 1)"/>
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform="scale(1, -1)"/>
        </symbol>

        <pattern id="pat1" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 200 200" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <use x="0" y="0" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c1"/>
            <use x="100" y="0" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c3"/>
            <use x="0" y="100" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c4"/>
            <use x="100" y="100" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c2"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="70" width="400" height="220" fill="url(#pat1)"></rect>

    <use href="#big1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" ></use>
</svg>
```

Прилагаю скриншот на случай если это глюк моего рендера (Yandex Browser)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот если размер паттерна сделать другой то всё работает нормально

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.c1 {
  fill: #ffd77a;
  stroke: #ffd77a; }

.c2 {
  fill: #ffed7a;
  stroke: #ffed7a; }

.c3 {
  fill: #fbff7a;
  stroke: #fbff7a; }

.c4 {
  fill: #e4ff7a;
  stroke: #e4ff7a; }

.c5 {
  fill: #ceff7a;
  stroke: #ceff7a; }

.c6 {
  fill: #b8ff7a;
  stroke: #b8ff7a; }

.c7 {
  fill: #a2ff7a;
  stroke: #a2ff7a; }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" style="width:400px; height: 400px;" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="el1" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50"></rect>
            <path d="M 30 0 L 0 30 L 0 0 Z" class="c5"></path>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="big1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform=""/>
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform="scale(-1, -1)"/>
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform="scale(-1, 1)"/>
            <use width="50" height="50" href="#el1" transform="scale(1, -1)"/>
        </symbol>

        <pattern id="pat1" width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 200 200" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <use x="0" y="0" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c1"/>
            <use x="100" y="0" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c3"/>
            <use x="0" y="100" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c4"/>
            <use x="100" y="100" width="100"  height="100" href="#big1" class="c2"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <rect x="0" y="70" width="400" height="220" fill="url(#pat1)"></rect>

    <use href="#big1" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="yellow" ></use>
</svg>
```

Во втором примере размер `pattern`'a не `50`, а `40`.

Вопрос в том, почему это так странно работает, и как правильно писать код чтобы таких артефактов не было.

Как поправить данный пример я методом проб и ошибок понял, можно сделать `stroke-width: 5px;` и артефакты пропадают. Но мне не понятна логика их появления.

На мой текущий уровень понимания я это понимаю так что при масштабировании какие-то величины делятся не нацело а результатом являются дробные величины которые при рендере вот так отображаются, поэтому для состыковки элементов нужно брать запас в пикселях, что бы покрыть неточности масштабирования, поворотов и переносов. И артефакт связан с внутренними особенностями алгоритма рендера.

Answer (score 3):

Проведя ряд тестов понял откуда берутся полосы. При размерах родительского элемента которые делятся нацело с размером паттерна - всё хорошо. Когда деление рождает дробные числа получаются зазоры.

Смысл в том что у меня в примере есть параллельные линии между элементами el1 и big1, при кратных размерах они рисуются вплотную, при дробных размерах появляется зазор.

Вероятно это связано с округлениями и особенностями алгоритма рисований кривых. В данном случае это надо понимать как данность и особенность рендера SVG, которую надо учитывать.

Вот пример для тестов. Верхние квадраты сделаны с размерами символа кратными разерам внутри символа. Нижние квадраты - некратные размеры. Как можно видеть в нижних квадратах появляется зазор. Специально что бы его было лучше видно добавил белые полосы, на границе легко отслеживается смена чёрного и белого.

```html
<svg style="width:500px; height:300px;background-color:black" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="s1" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="25" height="50" fill="pink"></rect>
            <rect x="25" y="0" width="25" height="50" fill="yellow"></rect>
        </symbol>
    </defs>

    <rect x="10" y="30" width="480" height="40" fill="white"/>
    <use href="#s1" x="20" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
    <use href="#s1" x="130" y="10" width="50" height="50"/>
    <use href="#s1" x="270" y="10" width="150" height="150"/>
    
    <rect x="10" y="170" width="480" height="40" fill="white"/>
    <use href="#s1" x="20" y="160" width="125" height="125"/>
    <use href="#s1" x="200" y="190" width="77" height="77"/>
</svg>
```

Привожу скриншот как это выглядит у меня на случай если у кого-то другой рендер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]